# Finding where links are

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

When I go to [this webpage](http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLibrary/toPPPList.do), I see green buttons with the text "信息公开". My task is to download all links of this green button. So if there are ten buttons, I need all ten links.

However I cannot find the text "信息公开" when I download the page in Chrome. I suspect that some Javascript is executed to download information related to "信息公开". Indeed, when I use Chrome to inspect the green buttons, I find information that I cannot find in the HTML files which I download.

How can I find out where the links are?

Comment: Have you tried using Phantom.js and scraping the links when the page has fully loaded?

Comment: Nope. I took a look at the website. It seems doable but are there comparable/easier alternatives which don't require downloading software?

Comment: Or is there some method which uses Python or R?

Comment: you could use chrome and use a jquery selector (should be enabled in the console) to scrape the links right from the loaded site

Comment: For example try this in you chrome console. you'll get all the links in the right yellow box here on SO `$('.community-bulletin a').each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('href'))})`

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant! Thanks. I'll try this as well as phantom.js

Comment: Can I put this as an answer for you?

Comment: Yes, please! That was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two JavaScript-based options:

a) Use a headless browser like Phantom.js to scrape the site for the links, there should be no problem with the JavaScript-loaded content. This would be the solution if you want to automate the scraping (like running it daily and posting the links somewhere)

b) Much simpler, but not as automatic: Use the jQuery in the Chrome Console to build a selector to get all the links. For example this piece of code, will give you the links of the yellow community box on the right side of Stack Overflow: 
`$('.community-bulletin a').each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('href'))})`